# MKR GSM 1400 Works only when connected to computer

Tags: mkr-gsm-1400

My MKR GSM 1400 works fine when connected to a computer (powered USB) and after opening a serial connection to it.  It does not when I plug it into a power supply. My power supply is a 5V 3A with a USB adapter.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //...
  while (!Serial);
  //...
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //...
}
```

Comment: What means that it does not work? What does actually happen? Also show us your code and your circuit. Currently you don't give us enough information to help you.

Comment: @chrisl The sketch doesn't run = It does not work. Is my power supply sufficient? Is it ok to power it through the USB connection or do I need to power it somewhere else? I don't think my code is the issue.

Comment: do you have `while (!Serial);` in the sketch?

Comment: How do you see, that it doesn't run? As asked: please say, what actually happens instead of what doesn't happen.

Comment: I’ll upload a minimal sketch later. I have an Xbee connected. The sketch makes an http request. If it were running I’d see data in the database. If I connect to the computer, it runs. I do use Serial to let me know what’s going on while connected to the computer.

Comment: It was the while(!serial)

Comment: I've posted a question with more details since I am having the same issue at: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77324/arduino-mkr-gsm-1400-fails-to-start-up-without-serial-monitor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your sketch on an Arduino with native USB doesn't run if not connected to USB, always first check if you didn't forget to disable a dependence on `Serial`.  A common error is a `while (!Serial) {}` endless loop in setup().