# What is required to run a program preciously uploaded and working from Arduino IDE via PC... (Nano 33 IoT)... but now powered via VIN, not USB?

Tags: arduino-nano-33-iot

The Arduino IDE works beautifully with the Nano 33 IoT using the IDE and is powered via USB. I now want to disconnect the USB and power thru the VIN pin (6-22V). The green led comes on but the program is not there or not running. Please help.  thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MKR GSM 1400 Works only when connected to computer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/69109/mkr-gsm-1400-works-only-when-connected-to-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload your code into the Arduino, it is there, burned into the flash memory of the microcontroller and it runs no matter how you power your board.

However, if in order to run your program is dependent on the Serial interface, for instance you added a line like `while(!Serial)` and you have not connected the USB cable, the program will loop at that point and will not continue.

For more information please upload your code.

Comment: you made the same error as OP. you didn't search for an existing answer